# What are the real and imaginary parts of the complex function?

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, several-complex-variables

So, it is asked to find the real and imaginary parts of the specific complex function:

$f(z)=sin(z)+i(3z+2) $
So I use $z$ as $z=x+iy$

everything seemed clear till I met Mr. Sinus:

$u+iv= sin(x+iy)+i(3(x+iy)+2)$

and I don't really know how to seperate the imaginary and real parts of $sin(x+iy)$ argument.

Need hints...

Comment: You probably know the addition theorem for the sine, $\sin (a+b) = \dotsc$. Set $a = x$ and $b = iy$. What are $\sin (iy)$ and $\cos (iy)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

use addition formula: $\sin(x+iy)=\sin x \cos(iy)+\cos x \sin(iy)$ and remember that: $ \cos(iy)=\cosh(y)\;$ and $ \sin(iy)=i\sinh y$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It was really useful. :)